# How can I make my form responsive on all sizes

Tags: html, css

I've been working on my form here: https://jsfiddle.net/8x49dzfq/

And I am trying my best to make the whole responsive by putting it inside a container.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #ABABAB; padding: 30px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; border-radius: 8px; text-align: center; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;">
```

But right now it's not yet responsive. As seen on this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/emwxwi

I want to make this form responsive on all screen sizes and put some spaces on each of the textboxes and padding to make them a bit large..

Any idea what am I supposed to do?

Comment: have you considered using bootstrap? it's great for mobile first responsive layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input, select, textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Give the element a width of 100% to make it fluid.

for example you want to apply these style in certain breakpoint. You can use media queries.

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  input, select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```